# if codeigniter enable query string in controller but could not redirect on my controller method? why

Tags: php, codeigniter

If codeigniter enable query string in controller but could not redirect on my controller method? why?
codeigniter config.php file providing this feature you have simply to activate rewrite this query

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

At the same time our controller could not to redirect the controller methods
For example I am used this version CodeIgniter v3.0.3 (Current version).

/home/test/Pictures/SDScreenshot from 2015-11-07

[image]

```
<?php
defined ('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allow');
class Route extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    function index()
    {
    $this->setting();
    }
    public function setting()
    {
    $object=&get_instance();
    $this->path();  
    }

    public function path()
    {
    $this->load->view('route_view');
    }   

    function log()
    {
    $base=site_url().'/Route/auto_range';
    redirect($base);
    }

    function auto_range()
    {
    echo 'simple auto_range is alreafy modified';


    }


}
```

Comment: You could use `redirect(base_url('Route/auto_range'))` instead of `$base=site_url().'/Route/auto_range';`